# Calculating Active dates based on gap length using Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, time-series

I'm relatively new to pandas, and trying to figure out what the best way of calculating this information is, so any help is much appreciated. Essentially I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
id     activity_date
1      2015-01-01      
1      2015-01-02      
1      2015-01-03      
2      2015-01-02      
2      2015-01-05     
3      2015-01-10
```

And I want to calculate the following information "How many days was each account active?", I understand that I could simply do a count to get this information, but I want to apply the following restriction, "If there are n days between activity dates, only count the days before that gap".

For example, with n = 5 the following should return the count of days active as 4, not 6

```
id     activity_date
1      2015-01-01      
1      2015-01-02      
1      2015-01-04
1      2015-01-06
1      2015-01-14
1      2015-01-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding what you want this is much simpler, so we calculate whether the difference between the current and previous rows is larger than 5 days giving us a boolean series, we use this filter the df and then use the index value to perform slicing:

```
In [57]:

inactive_index = df[df['activity_date'].diff() > pd.Timedelta(5, 'd')]
inactive_index
Out[57]:
   id activity_date
4   1    2015-01-14

In [18]:

inactive.index
Out[18]:
Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')
In [58]:

df.iloc[:inactive.index[0]]
Out[58]:
   id activity_date
0   1    2015-01-01
1   1    2015-01-02
2   1    2015-01-04
3   1    2015-01-06
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I think I might have made my condition unclear though so this might be calculating something different. Your snippet seems to sum the days where the timedelta is less than 5, I'm looking to drop the days after the first occurance of a 5 day delta, not just discount the day that has that delta. eg if you spend from the 1st to the 10th, then again from the 18th to the 30th, it's still just 10 days.

Comment: Sorry you'll have to explain how you arrive at 10 days from that example

Comment: So every day you spend is an "active day", any day you don't is an inactive  day, and if you have more than 5 inactive days in a row I want to essentially set a "deactivated" flag and stop counting active days.

Comment: So if the length of inactive days is greater than 5 then count up to this day correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it

Comment: Ed, that that edit was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Are you just focused on the dates themselves only if so the above will still work, if you're trying to calculate the inactive date per user that is different and slightly more complicated